# gdb python module can't find any function of it's own

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, gdb, gdb-python

I compiled&installed gdb(7.1.1) from the source code by doing `CC=gcc-6 ./configure --with-python=python3 && make` then `sudo make install`. Then I invoked gdb from bash as usual. But when I tried to load my python script within gdb by doing `source asdf.py`, it threw an error saying

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'execute'`

I tried to change my code to try more functions from the gdb module but every function I tried to execute was looking like it's missing. I invoked python interpreter within gdb then did `import gdb` and then `dir(gdb)` to see gdb's contents, the output was

`['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

So there really is a module called gdb but it's contents are empty. What could have gone wrong during installation? Or is this a bug in gdb? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you call any of your files `gdb.py`?

Comment: No, I didn't. Where is the gdb.py file anyways?

Comment: Dunno. That list of attributes, with `__path__` and no `__file__`, looks like what you'd get with a [namespace package](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). That'd happen if Python found one or more folders named `gdb` on the module search path, but it didn't find a `gdb.py` or a `gdb` folder with an `__init__.py`. That means GDB's `gdb` module isn't getting found.

Comment: I installed the previous gdb version I used to use to see how should a correct installation should look like and I noticed that gdb.py is located in `/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb` and the file is not empty. So while doing install, it didn't load any python libraries... interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the files needed for gdb is located at gdb/data-directory. So moving all files from to the place where python scripts should be did the trick.

```
sudo cp -R gdb/data-directory/* /usr/share/gdb/
```